# JPA CriteriaQuery having clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, h2

so I am working on a webapplication and I need to perform a query that retrieves me the most recent Projects, that have received a message. The Application is using JAX-RS and Hibernate to do its tasks. The table looks like this:

[image]
All i am interressted for are the unique projects, but those that have the max value in the updated column.

So normally I would create a subquery where I would sort everything by the updated column and in the out query call the distinct method retrieving a limited amount of rows. But apparantly sql does not want that and the criteriaQuery does not allow an orderby inside a subquery.

Any idea how I can make following query sql comfort(removing the nested query). It might not be syntacticly correct but it should be sufficient to get the idea of what I want it to do:

```
select distinct project from (select project,updated from Message order by updated) limit 5
```

I searched a lot and though that a group by combined with an having clause would solve my issue, but could not make it work either.

Comment: I found a solution by using the query posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226053/select-record-with-max-value-from-each-group-with-query-dsl

Realizable using subqueries in criteriaqueries. Edit: can someone make it so this question refers to above link? Basicly a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

To get the 5 most recent messages you can use:

```
List resultList = em.createQuery("select distinct m.project from Message m order by m.updated desc")
                    .setMaxResults(5)
                    .getResultList();
```

Comment: Unfortunatley this does not work. I get an error (its in german but I searched for the proper english version) "order by expression must be in the result list in this case"